# How can I get custom user registration field parameters

Tags: plugin-development, registration

I am allowing users to register on my site. I want to have the field "full name" on the registration page which, from there I will eventually split that value to populate the first name & last name fields for each user within the CP.

I have the actual in put in place:

**twig**

```
<h3><label for="fullName">Full Name</label></h3>
<input id="fullName" type="text" id="fullName" name="fields[fullName]"
{%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.fullName }}"{% endif -%}>

{% if account is defined %}
    {{ errorList(account.getErrors('fullName')) }}
{% endif %}
```

I have created a plugin to grab the value of the `fullName` input. I am using the `init()` method to listen for the `saveUser` event which is working perfectly.

**MyPlugin.php**

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('users.saveUser', function (Event $event) {
        error_log('-- saveUser event called --');
        error_log(print_r($event, true));

        if ($event->params['isNewUser']) {
            error_log('-- creating a new user --');

            error_log($event->params['fullName']);


            // split the fullname into firstname & lastname

            // populate first name

            // populate last name

            // save the new user
        } else {
            error_log('-- updating an existing user --');
        }
    });
}
```

I can see the data come through in the logs, but I'm not sure how to get to it.

**error_log**

```
...
[_attributes:Craft\BaseModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [locale] => en_us
                                [elementId] => 123
                                [fullName] => aaa bbb
                                [id] => 123
                            )
...
```

The "fullName" parameter is getting populated, but when I log the out put:

**MyPlugin.php**

```
error_log($event->params['fullName']);
```

I am getting the error `Undefined index: fullName`. The user *is* getting created.

I *can* get to the data using this:

```
craft()->request->getPost('fields.fullName');
```

But then I'm not sure how to get *that* back into the user model so it gets saved.

**EDIT**

Sigh, well if it isn't obvious I don't give up too easily. I am able to capture the data like this. Is this the correct way? I will have a large number of registrations, so I'm trying to do things the *correct* way as much as possible.

**MyPlugin.php**

```
$event->params['fullName'] = craft()->request->getPost('fields.fullName');
error_log($event->params['fullName']);  // aaa bbb
```

Here is is in the CP:
[image]

The trick I'm seeing now is how to inject (for lack of better words) the values from `fullName` into `firstName` and `lastName`.

Here is what I am using to try to do that (without much success)

```
$name = explode(' ', craft()->request->getPost('fields.fullName'));
$lastName = array_pop($name);
$firstName = implode(' ', $name);

$event->params['fullName'] = craft()->request->getPost('fields.fullName');
$event->params['firstName'] = $firstName;
$event->params['lastName'] = $lastName;
```

"Full Name" (as you can see in the attachment) is getting populated, but "First Name" and "Last Name" are not. In the logs I can see it:

```
 [isNewUser] => 1
 [fullName] => aaa bbb
 [firstName] => aaa
 [lastName] => bbb
```

But the First Name & Last Name fields in the user account tab are not getting populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [onSaveUser](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onSaveUser) event docs, there are two parameters that are passed to everyone listening.  One is `isNewUser`, which you're accessing correctly: `$event->params['isNewUser']`.  But the other is `user`, which is a full-blown [UserModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel) object that you can access the properties of.

But `onSaveUser` isn't the event you want, since you want to make changes to the user *before* they've been saved.  You want [onBeforeSaveUser](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onBeforeSaveUser), which has the exact same parameters.

Having said that, names are tricky things around the globe.  I highly recommend reading [this article](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) on falsehoods that programmers believe about names.

Here is some code that should work for the most basic use cases.

```
craft()->on('users.saveUser', function (Event $event) {

    // Only do this for new users.
    if ($event->params['isNewUser'])
    {
        $fullName = craft()->request->getPost('fields.fullName');

        // Make sure this isn't a user being saved from the control panel.
        if ($fullName)
        {
            $name = explode(' ', $fullName);

            // No spaces, it could be Madonna or Cher.
            if (count($name) == 1)
            {
                $firstName = $name[0];
                $lastName = '';
            }
            // It's a "normal" first and last name.
            else if ($count($name) == 2)
            {
                $firstName = $name[0];
                $lastName = $name[1];
            }
            else
            {
                // The first element is the first name. Combine the rest into a last name separated by spaces.
                $firstName = array_pop($name);
                $lastName = implode(' ', $name);
            }

            // Grab the user.
            $user = $event->params['user'];

            $user->firstName = $firstName;
            $user->lastName = $lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that UserModel already has a [getFullName](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/UserModel#getFullName-detail) method that does some basic logic combining the `firstName` and `lastName` properties.